# Pandas data frame gets sorted differently when filtering on different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using plotly dash for visual representation of data analysis that I have performed on database of IPL. I have bunch of csv that I have exported from sql views.

And now I am reading this csv with the help of pandas and giving the retrieved data based on my filters to plotly graph.

The problem is data comes sorted based on different columns when filter is applied on a different column, i.e. When I **filter data by season_id data comes sorted based on runs** and when I **filter data by team_bowling data comes sorted based on match_id.**

I am not able to understand this behavior of filtering or pandas data frame.

Here is my code and the output.

```
stats = pd.read_csv('data_files/All_Season_Batsman_Runs.csv', delimiter=',')
kohli = stats[stats.Player_Name == 'V Kohli'][stats.Season_Id == 1]
print(kohli)
```

[image: filter done by season]

```
stats = pd.read_csv('data_files/All_Season_Batsman_Runs.csv', delimiter=',')
kohli = stats[stats.Player_Name == 'V Kohli'][stats.Team_Bowling == 1]
print(kohli)
```

[image]

I am using

Pandas => 0.23.4

Python => 3.7

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the index numbers, the original file has some sorting already. Possibly by season and runs. Nothing unexpected as far is I can tell.

Comment: That doesn't explain why sorting is being changed, also notice that I am not filtering on the columns that are being sorted by pandas, so what could be the reason behind different sorting policies on both filter.

Comment: The sorting policy is by default: index, which gets set on file load. It's not being changed.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why I am getting two differently sorted results when I apply filter on differently columns, Here is the link to original file if you want to analyze it https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GiyHn2B04IeecC9XdgZENNQjJs6M_Dng

Comment: The file is indeed is default sorted by Season_Id, and then runs. When you apply your filter criteria in spreadsheets, you get the same results as pandas. What is the expected result?

Comment: Why am I getting result sorted by match_id when filter is applied on team_bowling, if default sorting is by season_id and runs then I should never get a result sorted by match_id, isn't it?

Comment: If you look closely to the match id, it is not sorted.